# Should I import package if it contains the same name part?

Tags: go, package

I have a bit weird question. Do I need import 2 packages in Go if it contain half of other package name?

For example should I import **"os"** if I already imported **"os/exec"**

Answer (score 1):

No. In fact, you can't even if you want to.  Importing a package you don't directly reference will prevent Go from compiling.  See [this example](https://play.golang.org/p/MZEZlthu9B4):

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    _ = exec.Cmd{}
}
```

Produces this compilation error:

> ./prog.go:4:2: imported and not used: "os"

You import `os/exec` only if you need the functionality in `os/exec`, and you import `os` only if you need the functionality in `os`.

In some (but definitely not all) cases, a package `x/y` may depend on `x`, but it will import that itself, so you don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

### Wrong

```
package main

import (
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    _ = exec.Cmd{}
    _, _ = os.Getwd()
}
```

The above code will throw an error

> undefined: os

because we did not import the `os` package. The correct implementation is:

### Right

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    _ = exec.Cmd{}
    _, _ = os.Getwd()
}
```

### Wrong

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    _ = exec.Cmd{}
}
```

The above code will throw an error

> imported and not used: "os"

because we did not used the `os` package. The correct implementation is:

### Right

```
package main

import (
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    _ = exec.Cmd{}
}
```

So if you need the functionalities of `os` package then you should import it and if you need the functionalities of `os/exec` you should also need to import it explicitly. Otherwise, it is not needed to import both `os` and `os/exec` in the case where you only want one of them in your code.

Comment: @Flimzy ```For example should I import "os" if I already imported "os/exec"``` I give the answer to this question.

Comment: That's my answer too, but I give muliple code examples for clarity thats all :)

Comment: Your answer takes a different (and I believe incorrect) interpretation of the question.

Comment: @Flimzy may be its a sort of communication or language problem

Comment: I added more description in my answer I think it may be sufficient